# UWP update itemscontrol freeze ui

Tags: c#, uwp

I spent last 3 days on searching way to avoid freezing main (UI) thread while setting itemsource of my itemscontrol, but with out succes. I have itemsControl named items_control and setting itemsource as following 
`items_control.ItemsSource = await GetItems();` and GetItems method

```
       public async Task<ObservableCollection<UserControl>> GetItems()
        {
            ObservableCollection<UserControl> items = new ObservableCollection<UserControl>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
                items.Add(new MyUserControl());
            }
            return items;
        }
```

MyUserControl is my own control with some text, and calculations within. ofc ItemsControl is being virtualized by replacing itemsPanel with virtualizedStackPanel.

Comment: When asking about concrete problems with code you should avoid posting code that has no chance to compile (unless problem is indeed compile time error which does not sound like your case).

Comment: ok sorry my bad, now its compiling.

Comment: Your approach is totally wrong. You shouldn't return any UI element from a Task. As a matter of fact your code should deal with *data*, not UI elements. delete all that and use proper XAML and DataBinding.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, at begining im setting datacontext of my ItemsControl to Obeservable Collection<UserControl> and then just passing this observableCollection to my GetItems Method and its still freezing, i've noticed that if im adding 40 plain Grid Controls instead of my own UserControl (which has disabled all methods inside, just plain layout - some buttons and textblocks) its works fine, no freezing.